# Некорректно отображает русский шрифт

Tags: java, строки, кодировка, locale

Есть метод, который в зависимости от локали пользователя выводит сообщение. Проблема в том, что не отображаются русские символы. Я получаю такой вид

`������ �����, Kiev`, а с английским все нормально `Good evening, Kiev`.

Думал, может проблема в кодировки, не помогло. Вот код метода:

```
public static void VuvodPriv(ResourceBundle bundle, String gorod, double time)
{
    try {
        if (time >= 6.00 && time <= 9.00) {
            String key = bundle.getString("Utro");
            String s1 = new String(key.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
            System.out.println(s1 + gorod);
        } else if (time > 9.00 && time <= 19.00) {
            String key = bundle.getString("Den");
            String s1 = new String(key.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
            System.out.println(s1 + gorod);
        } else if (time > 19.00 && time <= 23.00) {
            String key = bundle.getString("Vecher");
            String s1 = new String(key.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
            System.out.println(s1 + gorod);
        } else if (time > 23.00 && time < 6.00) {
            String key = bundle.getString("Noch");
            String s1 = new String(key.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
            System.out.println(s1 + gorod);
        }
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

Locale current = Locale.getDefault();
ResourceBundle bundle1 = ResourceBundle.getBundle("text",current);
```

И сам `properties` по умолчанию:

```
Utro = Доброе утро, 
Den = Добрый день,
Vecher = Добрый вечер, 
Noch = Доброй ночи,
```

Comment: Очевидно же что проблема в локали

Comment: Очевидно же, что `ISO-8859-1` - это `Latin-1` и в ней в принципе нет русских символов

Comment: @КириллМатасов, @ rjhdby, ну видимо не всем очевидно. Проблема в том что даже когда я с файла считываю текст, и если там есть русские символы, то их тоже не выводит корректно. Без кодировок тоже не отображает правильно.

Answer (score 1):

для ясности было бы неплохо взглянуть на ресурсный файл.
предполагаю, что он сохранен в неправильной кодировке, т.е. не в той в которой читается.
если он грузиться (по умолчанию) через PropertyResourceBundle то файл должен быть сохранен в кодировке ISO-8859-1

> The property file read with this constructor
>   must be encoded in ISO-8859-1. 
>   т.е. не латинские символы должны быть "заэскейплены"
>   например:

```
km = \u043A\u043C
```

иначе, если хочется иметь читабельные файлы, придется имплементить свой `ResourceBundle.Control` и использовать его при создании `bundle`.

Comment: Выше привел запись ресурсного файла, при созданий ничего не менял. Если не менять кодировку, то вывод будет таким "Äîáðûé äåíü, Kiev", хотя с английским текстом все норм.

Answer (score 0):

Если файл загружали через java.ioBufferedReader, то он испорчен, загружайте побайтово. А что-бы получить кириллицу из Latin-1 (если он не испорчен) я использовал этот код:

```
     byte[] iso_8859_1_Bytes = new String(latin1Bytes, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1).getBytes();
     String text = "";
     int i;
     int index = 0;
     while (index < iso_8859_1_Bytes.length) {
         if (index < iso_8859_1_Bytes.length - 1 && (i = (iso_8859_1_Bytes[index] & 0xff) << 8 | (iso_8859_1_Bytes[index + 1] &
 0xff)) >= 50048 && i <= 50303) {
             text += Character.toString((char) (i - 49008));
             index ++;
         } else {
             text += Character.toString((char) (iso_8859_1_Bytes[index] & 0xff));
         }
         index ++;
     }
```